# Get metadata of model (TableName) in mvc4 Using t4 Scaffolding

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, t4, asp.net-mvc-3-areas, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding

Using MVC4 and T4 Template(Scaffolding)
I am creating a model in mvc4 and specify the table name in DBContext.
1)I need to get the table from Dbcontext against model name.
2)Need to get value from annotation Table.

```
[Table(name: "Pay_Emp_Qualifications", Schema = "Sample")]
public class EmpQualification
{
    [Key]
    public int EMP_QUALI_ID { get; set; }
    public String Qualification { get; set; }
}
```

Currently we getting load the dll against the model and using reflection we get.We are trying to avoid this dll

```
var  objFile= Assembly.LoadFile(@"bin\wbtest.dll");
```

var objMaster = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Load(new AssemblyName(Convert.ToString(objFile))).CreateInstance(namespaceInstance);

```
 var attributeData = objMaster.GetType().GetCustomAttributesData().Select(p =>           p.ConstructorArguments).ToArray();
           var tableNameVariable= attributeData[0][0].Value.ToString();
```

How to get table name against model name in t4 template without using dll,we using ModelProperty class.
Please Suggest.

Comment: if the question is unclear please ask.

Answer (score 0):

While this doesn't exactly answer your question, it gives you an alternative way of loading the assembly so that it doesn't lock it.  [T4 and MSBuild integration issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8252818/t4-and-msbuild-integration-issues/18936478#18936478)